# Testing child_process.exec stdout

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to test the output of child process with mocha.

My test looks like this:

```
var should = require("should"),
    exec = require("child_process").exec;

describe('users', function() {
  describe('andrei', function() {
    exec('id andrei', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      it('should be part of group dev', function() {
        stdout.should.containEql('dev');
      })
    })
  })
})
```

The problem I'm having is that the `it` never gets executed.

I could swap the code around, to have the `exec` inside the `it` and then use `done` to ensure things run in the right order, but that would mean I'd have to run the same exec for each test I want to make against the child's stdout.

How can I have multiple `it` statements against the stdout of a child process?

Answer (score 20):

Mocha is not designed to run the code you show in your question. You could think of it as running in two phases. In the first phase, it reads all of your test files and executes them. The way it knows what tests you have in your suite is by executing all callback to `describe` immediately, and each time it encounters `it` it records is as a test to be run *later*. In the second phase, it runs the tests. So for a test to be visible to Mocha, it has to have seen an `it` call for it in the first phase. The code you show will prevent this from happening.

> How can I have multiple it statements against the stdout of a child process?

It sounds like you're aiming for one assertion per `it`. I'm not sure why you want to do this in your specific case. Multiple assertions in the same test is perfectly fine. At any rate, if you must do it then you could use a `before` hook:

```
var should = require("should"),
    exec = require("child_process").exec;

describe('users', function() {
    describe('andrei', function() {
        var captured_stdout;

        before(function (done) {
            exec('id andrei', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                if (error) done(error); // Handle errors.
                captured_stdout = stdout;
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should be part of group dev', function() {
            captured_stdout.should.containEql('dev');
        });
    });
});
```

The callback passed to `before` will be run before all the tests in the parent `describe`. The data to be tested is captured in `captured_stdout` and then the tests can all access it and test against it.

Comment: ~200 views but no upvotes? + 1 for tutorial-like answer and explaination.

Answer (score 2):

Years later, mocha has matured and [supports testing asynchronous code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

Simply add a callback (usually named `done`) to `it()` and Mocha will know that it should wait for this function to be called to complete the test.

```
const should = require("should"),
    { exec } = require("child_process");

describe('users', function() {
  describe('andrei', function() {
    it('should be part of group dev', function(done) {
      exec('id andrei', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        stdout.should.containEql('dev');
        done();
      })
    })
  })
})
```